# Reclassifying polygon ID in vectorized raster according to different layer

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, rivers

Goal: I am trying to create a lookup table for depth according to three discharge levels of a river, 250 cfs, 800 cfs, and 1500 cfs. I have raster files for all three that I have vectorized into polygons so that each raster cell is now a "patch" with an associated depth value (see photos below).

Issue: The patch IDs do not line up in each layer because at 1500 cfs, there is more area inundated, therefore the patches are numbered differently. I need to renumber the patches in the lower discharge file according to the patches in the higher discharge file, so that patch IDs are removed if the patch is no longer there because it is not inundated at lower flow. It's been suggested to me to make a new field for all three that is based on the higher cfs one, but I can't figure out a straightforward way to do this.

[image: 250 cfs]

[image: 800 cfs]

[image: 1500 cfs]

Comment: I don't really follow what you're trying to do but I would advise that polygon ids (FID, OID or ObjectID) are not able to be modified, yes you will need to add a new field. I sort-of get the impression that a solution would involve a spatial selection, have a read of https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_queries.html and see if that illuminates a workflow to your desired solution.

Comment: Any particular reason why you've converted from raster to vector in the first place? It seems like raster data would be easier to work with.